# How to set EntityManagerFactory name on a Spring JPA Repository?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have multiple database connections with named EntityManagers:

```
@Bean(name = "integDB")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "integEM")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean integDbEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
     ....
}
```

How do I specify which entity manager to use here?

```
@Repository
public interface IntControleFilaRepository extends JpaRepository<IntControleFilaEntity, String> {

}
```

Spring is complaining about it:
Parameter 0 of constructor in ... required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Create a configuration class for each database and specify the entityManager associated with each one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"..."}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "integEM", transactionManagerRef = "integTM")
public class IntegReposConfig {
}
```